# Created a project in react-native but when giving npx react-native run-android some errors keeps popping

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, java-deployment-toolkit

I just installed react-native today, i dont have any prior knowledge was following tutorial and when i tried to run the app it keeps showing the error.

screenshot of the error message

[image: screenshot of the error message]

screenshot of emulator opening when the command is given

[image: screenshot of emulator opening when the command is given]

this is the screenshot of cmd with the error.
Can someone help me solve the error.
If i have to add any more info please tell me i will do the same.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the emulator running?

Comment: Well the emulator opens and will be in home screen.